# How to get the values or texts from HTML select tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

In my html file i have the following:

```html
<td id="trainers_rowC1">Trainer1</td>

<td><input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_rowC('1')"></td>
```

In my JavaScript file i have this function:

```js
function edit_rowC(no) {
    var trainers = document.getElementById("trainers_rowC" + no);
    var trainers_data = trainers.innerHTML;
    trainers.innerHTML = "<select id ='trainers_options" + no + "'><option value='" + trainers_data + "'>";
}
```

But when i press the Edit button the dropdown menu is empty. What is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

Your mistake was that you tried to set the content of the option tag with `value="..."`. But you have to write it between the two tags. --> `<option>" + test + "</option>`

```js
function edit_rowC(no) {
    var test = document.getElementById("trainers_rowC" + no).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("trainers_rowC" + no).innerHTML = "<td><select id ='trainers_options" + no + "'><option>" + test + "</option><option>test</option></select></td>";
}
```

Comment: please accept the answear as accepted if the answear solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any closing tags in the assignment of trainers.innerHTML - could that be it?

Comment: I put the </option></select> at the end but i am still facing the same problem.